# AWS Lambda Python Boto3 - Inserting data into dynamodb throws error ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the PutItem operation: Requested resou",

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3

AWS is buggy I think. I didn't make any change to the code. Today it is working fine. I struggled all day

I am reading the content of a file from S3 and trying to insert data into Dynamodb table.
Everything works right up until inserting data into the dynamodb table. The table exists but it says resource not found
Both Lambda and Dynamodb exist in the same region.

It says: "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the PutItem operation: Requested resource not found",
"errorType": "ResourceNotFoundException",

I tried describe the table. that also throws error

```
dbclient = boto3.session('dynamodb')
response = dbclient.describe_table(TableName='USBCallCenterTable')
print(response)
```

---

```
import json
import boto3
from pprint import pprint

def lambda_handler(event, context):   
    session = boto3.session.Session()   
    s3_client = session.client('s3')


    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket_name=record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key_name = record['s3']['object']['key']
        #pprint(dir(record))
        #print(bucket,key)
    
    response =  s3_client.get_object(Bucket = bucket_name, Key = key_name)

    #convert streaming data to byte
    content = response['Body'].read()

    ##convert the byte into string
    data_inString = content.decode('UTF-8')

    ##convert the string data into dictionary 
    data_inDictionary = json.loads(data_inString)
    print(data_inDictionary)

    dynamodbtable = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodbtable.Table('customer')
    table.put_item(Item=data_inDictionary)
```

[image]

Comment: can you give exact error ? with traceback ?

Comment: from the initial error, it seems like it `role` associated with lambda function don't have permission or that table is not exists.

Comment: Nilesh. this is the stack trace

Comment: I gave AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess policy to the role and the table exists. I am able to add data manually thru the console to the table

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct region in the lambda handler.

Comment: can you try `get_item` and see if that works ?

Comment: rdas, they exist in same region

Comment: `If the specified table does not exist, DynamoDB returns a ResourceNotFoundException` this is what documentation mentioned https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.delete_table, if you are able to see the table, there might be something which is not able to see.

Comment: Nilesh, I tried to describe the table it throws ''module object is not callable'                        "errorMessage": "'module' object is not callable",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "requestId": "2e94a42e-29cb-485c-8ea3-1314d1a551c9",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 42, in lambda_handler\n    dbclient = boto3.session('dynamodb')\n"
  ]
   dbclient = boto3.session('dynamodb')
   response = dbclient.describe_table(TableName='USBCallCenterTable')
   print(response)

Comment: Is your Lambda in a VPC? do you use a VPC endpoint for S3 connection?

Comment: No it is not in a VPC. I am looking at the configuration--> VPC nothing exists there I tried deleting items in that table. It throws same error... dynamodbtable1 = boto3.client('dynamodb')
   response = dynamodbtable1.delete_item(
                    Key={
                         'agentId': {'N': '7' },
                         'agentRole': {'S': 'agentRole'},
                       },
                    TableName='USBCallCenterTable'
                    )

Comment: You're likely in the wrong region or in the wrong AWS account. Print the value of `session.region_name`. Is it what you expected? Print the value of `list(dynamodbtable.tables.all())`. It should be a list of tables in the current region. Is it what you expected? Print the value of `boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity()`. Is it the IAM identity and AWS account that you expected?

Comment: Or you've mis-spelled the table name.

Comment: jarmod, I don't know what to say. I didn't make any change to the code. It worked fine this morning. I am confused to why it didn't work yesterda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a plain lambda and table in a region and was able to run your python code above successfully.  There does not appear to be an error in your code.

Note that when I first deployed your code, I forgot to update the table name and received the exact same error you received.  Once I fixed the table name it worked as expected.

Comment: thank You Coin. It worked fine without any problem today